# JSON Order MixedUp

Tags: javascript, node.js

My application generates a JSON file. When there is an update, the generated JSON file gets updated. The order gets mixed up. When I see the diff even though the files are not much changed, the diff shows as if there is a huge changes because the file contents are rearranged (mixed up). Is there any way I can have the same order of file contents so that my diff looks clean.

---

Assume the content of `one.json` is

```
{
  "test": {
    "key": "test",
    "value": "test"
  },
  "test1": {
    "key": "test1",
    "value": "test1"
  }
}
```

After the update

```
{
  "test2": {
    "key": "test2",
    "value": "test2"
  },
  "test1": {
    "key": "test1",
    "value": "test1"
  },
  "test": {
    "key": "test",
    "value": "test"
  }
```

Rather I need the update to be:

```
{
  "test": {
    "key": "test",
    "value": "test"
  },
  "test1" : {
    "key": "test1",
    "value": "test1"
  },
  "test2" : {
    "key": "test2",
    "value": "test2"
  }
}
```

Comment: The order of *what* is mixed up?

Comment: The JSON file content order is mixed up.
Assume the content of  one.json is 

"test": {
        "key": "test",
        "value": "test"
        },
        "test1" : {
        "key": "test1",
        "value": "test1"
        }

After the update
  "test2" : {
        "key": "test2",
        "value": "test2"
        },
        "test1" : {
        "key": "test1",
        "value": "test1"
        },
        "test": {
        "key": "test",
        "value": "test"
        }

Rather I need the output to be

Comment: The only JSON serialisable object that implies any sort of *order* is an array. Is that what you're talking about? Perhaps you should show some examples

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript object key order is not guaranteed, nor is it important.

If the order of your *test* items **is** important, I suggest you use an array

```
[{
  "key": "test",
  "value": "test"
}, {
  "key": "test1",
  "value": "test1"
}, {
  "key": "test2",
  "value": "test2"
}]
```